# Dice and Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a Bernoulli random variable of parameter $p$. This means that $X=1$ with probability $p$. Now, if $X = 1$, then Alice tosses $4$ fair coins, whereas if $X = 0$, she tosses 6 fair coins.

1. Which is the probability that Alice sees 5 heads?

Note: In view of the first answer, if we call $5H$ the event "Alice sees 5 heads", I get $P(5H|X=0)=P(5H \cap X=0)=P(5H)$, i.e. the probability of coming up with 5 heads when tossing 6 dice. If I computed well, such a probability equals $\binom{6}{5} (\frac{1}{2})^5$.

2. Compute the probability that Alice sees 2 heads.

I have to use the law of total probability. In fact, I get $P(2H \cap X=0)+P(2H \cap X=1)$. In this case, which is the probability? Should I make my computation as in the case $1)$? If yes, how the parameter $p$ is involved?

3. Compute the probability that $X = 1$, given that Alice sees 2 heads.

My answer
$$
P(X=1|2H)=\frac{P(2H|X=1)P(X=1)}{P(2H)}
$$
Here $P(2H|X=1)=\frac{P(2H \cap X=1)}{P(X=1)}$ and $P(2H)$ has been already computed above.

4. Determine for which value of p the probability in 3) equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

I think that the formula in 3) depends on $p$, so that by equating to $\frac{1}{2}$ I need only to solve an equation.

Comment: For part 1, she gets 5 H in 6 throws, so what is the *unconditional* probability of this ? Try them one by one and show where you are stuck

Comment: @trueblueanil $\binom{6}{5} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^5$? Please, can you provide a complete answer, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per protocol, I am not supposed to give answers unless you show your effort, so I'll give you hints

**HINTS**

1. To get 5H, Alice must have got $X=0$ with probability $(1-p)$ *and* got $5H$ in $6$ tosses, thus $(1-p)\binom65(\frac12)^5(\frac12)^1$
2. Now there will be two streams, use the law of total probability
3. After doing the first two, you should be ready to use Bayes' Theorem
4. Your thinking is right.

Comment: I edited my question, giving some other details and partial answers. Please, can you edit your answer suitably, providing the required details?

Comment: I have given full details for **1**, revise others in line.

Comment: Is the argument I provided for part 3) correct?

Comment: Yea, the formula is ok.